# My BubbleSort class does not count iterations correctly

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

This is my my program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] arrayToSort = new int[] { 5,4,9};
            BubbleSort bubbleSort = new BubbleSort();
            int [] SortedArray = bubbleSort.SortArray(arrayToSort);
            foreach (int i in SortedArray)
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + "," );
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Iterations {0}",   
                               bubbleSort.IterationsCounter);
            Console.ReadLine();    

        }

 public class BubbleSort
    {
        public int IterationsCounter;
        public int[] SortArray(int[] arrayToSort)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<arrayToSort.Length-1;i++)
            {
                if(arrayToSort[i]>arrayToSort[i+1])
                {
                    int temp=arrayToSort[i];
                    arrayToSort[i]=arrayToSort[i+1];
                    arrayToSort[i+1]=temp;
                    //IterationsCounter++;  Update:Moved this line out of if condition)
                    SortArray(arrayToSort);
                }
            IterationsCounter++; //Moved counter here:

            }
            return arrayToSort;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
4,5,9 Number of Iterations:1
```

How can that be right? I mean the array IS sorted but surely there was more than one iteration. I was expecting this to have O(N^2) running time but something is off here. Am I not counting the iterations right?

**EDIT:**

OK I realized 3 items isn't enough AND as per the suggestion I moved the counter out of **if** , , if now i change the input to

```
 5,4,9,2,3,1,17
```

Number of iterations changes to `78` . Thats better( in the sense that it should be high) but its not high enough. So then this means the algorithm has O(logn) time? I thought bubblesort was O(n^2)?

Thank you

Comment: Just so you get put off Bubble-Sort, try with 10,000 items in the array.

Comment: I highly doubt it's not counting right, that's very unlikely and very scary if true! I would set a break point and watch it.

Comment: You're not counting iterations. You're counting swaps

Comment: Move your counter outside of the conditional and into the loop and it will produce the output you expect.

Comment: To respond to your last edit- it's been proven that it is impossible for any sorting algorithm to ever be in O(log(n)) time because you always have to visit every node at least once to check if the list is sorted. Bubblesort is indeed O(n^2) average time, with its best case being linear.

Comment: @gr3co oh....so bubble sort is O(n^2) on Average? not always..that makes sense.so then my algorithm might not take O(n^2) time)

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it, well it's always O(n^2) because O(n) < O(n^2). Think about a worst case scenario-- if your array is in reverse order, then your algorithm is going to have to move every single element across every other element. n elements * O(n) comparisons = O(n^2) time. Whereas in your best case, the array is already sorted. So your algorithm checks every element, sees that theyre in order, and just returns that array. Checkign every element is an O(n) operation so that's your best case.

Comment: I don't think you have understood the `O` concept. `O(n^2)` does not mean that the algorithm uses 100 operations for n=10. `O(n^2)` means that the algorith uses (on average or at most) 10*10 times as many operations as it does (on average or at most) when you increase the length of the input array tenfold. An algorithm can require 1000 operations for n=3 and still be `O(n)`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck that is the answer i was looking for... I thought O(n^2) meant it will always take that many operations.... +1 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are counting the number of swap operation, not the iterations. The average running time of Bubble sort is O(n^2), and it doesn't mean every bubble sort must do so many iterations. For example, if you bubble sort a sorted array, and set a flag if a swap is made after an entire pass over the array. If no swap is made, then it should be clear that the array is already in order because no two elements need to be swapped. In that case, the bubble sort should end. It seems faster than quicksort whose average time complexity is O(n log n) since the performance of the modified bubble sort is O(N) in this scenario. But you must take account of the general cases.

Answer (score 0):

Put IterationsCounter++; outside the if loop to count the number of iterations.
As of now the code will just count the number of swaps since it gets incremented only when there is swap.

Comment: Thanks, that increases the counter but still its not producing O(N^2), its still O(logn).... i.e. 4 items don't produce 16 iterations, 5 don't produce 25 and so on

Comment: It will not always produce O(N^2). It varies depending on your input.Try sorting an which is sorted in ascending order as an array in descending order. Eg sort 4,3,2,1 to ascending.